# Flatpickr Clear Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, flatpickr

I'm loading flatpickr using this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#Mydatetime').flatpickr({
        altInput: true,
        altFormat: "M j, Y @ H:i",
        enableTime: true,
        dateFormat: 'Y-m-d\\TH:i'
    });
});
```

```
<input type="text" id="Mydatetime" class="MyDate" name="my_expire_date" value="' . $variable . '"/>
```

The variable is just my datetime. It works, but I'd like to add a clear button similar to [this](https://chmln.github.io/flatpickr/examples/#flatpickr-external-elements). No matter what I do the button doesn't clear the date.

The example:

```
<a class="input-button" title="clear" data-clear>
    <i class="icon-close"></i>
</a>
```

Seems straightforward, but I'm clearly missing something. Anyone got one of these close buttons working properly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the following method:

```
const $flatpickr = $("#flatpickr_id").flatpickr();

$("#some_button_id").click(function() {
   $flatpickr.clear();
})
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$(function() {
  $(".input_button").click(function() {
    $('#Mydatetime')[0]._flatpickr.clear();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add this button to your HTML:

```
<button class="clear_button" title="clear" data-clear>
Clear
</button>
```

And add this code to the inside of "document ready" function

```
  $(".clear_button").click(function() {
    $('#Mydatetime').flatpickr().clear();
  })
```

Here is an working example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pxKOGP

Comment: This worked. Is this the prescribed method from Flatpickr though? Their example is very unclear me - such as why you'd need the "wrap" and why you'd need the "data-clear" attribute when it doesn't seem to be used.

Comment: @SalCangeloso you can clear the `title="clear" data-clear` code from HTML. But if you remove the clear_button class it will not work. I got from documentation.

Comment: Copied from answer by Adbul: "Answer by @Ayxan is not right, what it's doing is making a new instance of flatpickr and calling `clear()` on it. Most importantly it doesn't clear the hidden input fields that actually stores the date."

Answer (score 1):

If not using jQuery, you can try this:

```
const my_fp = document.querySelector("#fp_field")._flatpickr;
my_fp.clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `readonly` attribute

```
 <input readonly="readonly" placeholder="Select a Destination" />
```

and then do all the magic with JS.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve it using CoffeeScript/JS. Unfortunately, there is no option provided by the flatpickr to clear the field after selection.

Envoirenment: Rails & coffeescript

**View:**

```
<div class="form-group flatpicker">
        <%= f.label :start_time_gt_eq, 'Starting at', class: 'form-control-label font-weight-bold' %>
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-between ml-1">
          <%= f.text_field :start_time_gt_eq, class: 'form-control active position-relative col-md-11' ,
              data: {
                behavior: 'flatpickr_time',
                enable_time: true,
                alt_input: true,
              } %>
          <button type="button" id="appointment-start-from" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
        </div>
      </div>
```

**CoffeeScript file**

```
(->
  window.Appointments or (window.Appointments = {})

  Appointments.init = ->
    $ ->
      $('#appointment-start-from').click ->
        $('#q_start_time_gt_eq').flatpickr().clear();

      return
        
).call this
```

And make sure to initialize the JS in the view file

```
<% content_for :js_init do %>
  Appointments.init();
<% end %>
```